# Can radio waves be converted to positron and electron when placed in weak electric field?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, radio-frequency, pair-production

In particle physics, gamma rays can be converted to positron and electron when placed in strong electric field.

My question is: What will happen if radio waves are placed in weak electric field?
Will the radio wave be converted to positron and electron?

Answer (score 3):

Energy conservation holds. The two photons you start with, they together need to have at least as much energy as the restmass of the electron and positron. So for usual meanings of the word "weak": no, radio waves in a weak electric field do not convert.

Comment: It is interesting to read about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect, "The Schwinger effect is a predicted physical phenomenon whereby matter is created by a strong electric field. "